# Date array sorting issue, iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsdate, date-sorting

I have an array that contains different date values. And I have used the following code to sort the date array, its done.

```
    combinedArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger counts = [pbTitle count];
for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++) {

    CustomObject *customobject2 = [CustomObject customObjectWithName:
                                   [pbTitle objectAtIndex:i] andDate:[pbstartDate objectAtIndex:i]];
    [combinedArr addObject:customobject2];
}
[combinedArr sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)
 {
     return [[(CustomObject*)obj1 date]compare: [(CustomObject*)obj2 date]];
 }];
NSLog(@"Results: %@", combinedArr);
```

Now the result is in the combinedArr, I need to check the each value with current system time and need to load into two different arrays, and load these two arrays into two sections of a tableView. How can I implement that? Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the simplest and the fastest (shorter running time) solution is to create 2 separate arrays from the beginning and sort each one separately.

Like this:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSMutableArray *pastArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *futureArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger counts = [pbTitle count];

// Fill the arrays
for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++) {
    NSDate *customOnjectDate = [pbstartDate objectAtIndex:i];
    CustomObject *customobject2 = [CustomObject customObjectWithName:[pbTitle objectAtIndex:i] andDate:customOnjectDate];

    NSMutableArray *array = ([customOnjectDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedAscending ? pastArray : futureArray);
    [array addObject:customobject2];
}

// Sort the arrays
[pastArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
     return [[obj1 date] compare:[obj2 date]];
 }];
[futureArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
     return [[obj1 date] compare:[obj2 date]];
 }];

// Use the arrays
NSLog(@"pastArray: %@", pastArray);
NSLog(@"futureArray: %@", futureArray);

// Don't forget to release the arrays after you use them
[pastArray release];
[futureArray release];
```